# Highcharts - is possible to have stackLabels only for a subset of the series?

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart in which I combine a stacked column chart with a stacked line chart. I would like to have stackLabels for the column chart only, and suppress the stackLabels for the stacked line chart.

It currently looks like this:
[image]

How can I achieve stack labels **ONLY** on the column chart?

Also see https://jsfiddle.net/o1bqwu7r/4/ or :

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
  yAxis: {
     stackLabels: {
         enabled: true
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        },
       
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        type: 'column'
    }, {
        data: [144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2],
        type: 'column'
    }, {
        data: [2.9, 7.5, 16.4, 12.2, 14.0, 17.0, 13.6, 14.5, 21.4, 19.1, 9.6, 5.4],
        type: 'line'
    }, {
        data: [14.0, 17.0, 13.6, 14.5, 21.4, 19.1, 9.6, 5.4, 2.9, 7.5, 10.4, 12.2],
        type: 'line'
    },]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a separate `yAxis` for the line series:

```
yAxis: [{
    stackLabels: {
        enabled: true
    }
}, {
    linkedTo: 0,
    visible: false
}],

series: [{
    data: [...],
    type: 'column'
}, {
    data: [...],
    type: 'column'
}, {
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [...],
    type: 'line'
}, {
    yAxis: 1,
    data: [...],
    type: 'line'
}]
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1ojnakzw/1/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis